# Comportamiento de vectores en c++

Tags: c++

Debo crear un arreglo de 5 posiciones que almacene enteros y realizar:

- Mostrar el numero mayor
- Mostrar los multiplos de 5 del arreglo

El programa ya me da la información que necesito, pero el problema es que me repite cierta información y es posible que en algún contador (for) se me este acumulando dicha información para que esta se repita nuevamente. Me gustaría saber en donde esta el problema para darle su respectiva solución.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (){

    int numeros [5],numeroMayor=0,multiplos[5]={0};

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        cout<<"Ingrese el elemento "<<i+1<<" del vector"<<endl;
        cin>>numeros[i];
        cout<<endl;

        if(numeros[i]>numeroMayor){
            numeroMayor = numeros[i];
        }

        if(numeros[i] % 5 == 0){
            multiplos[i] = numeros[i];
        }
    }

    cout<<"El numero mayor es: "<<numeroMayor<<endl;

    for (int i=0; i<multiplos[i]; i++){
        cout<<"El numero "<<multiplos[i]<<" es multiplo de 5 "<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Lo que ocurre es lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esa información de los multiplos de 5, en este caso, solo tendrían que salir las 5 primeras veces porque le ingrese 5 elementos al vector que cumplen la condicional (si son o no multiplos), pero me la esta devolviendo otras 5 veces adicional (en total 10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nota que el segundo bloque está mal.

El array `multiplos` únicamente tiene 5 elementos ... tu bucle está asumiendo que tiene `multiplos[i]` elementos!!!

```
for (int i=0; i<multiplos[i]; i++){
    cout<<"El numero "<<multiplos[i]<<" es multiplo de 5 "<<endl;
}
```

Basta con corregir la comparación de tu bucle:

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
    cout<<"El numero "<<multiplos[i]<<" es multiplo de 5 "<<endl;
}
```

Aunque ya puestos quedaría más limpio si expresamos el límite con una expresión constante. Esta práctica te permitiría jugar facilmente con el número de elementos que maneja la aplicación simplemente tocando una línea de código:

```
constexpr int MAX_ELEMENTOS = 5;

int numeros [MAX_ELEMENTOS], int multiplos[MAX_ELEMENTOS];

for (int i=0; i<MAX_ELEMENTOS; i++){
    cout<<"El numero "<<multiplos[i]<<" es multiplo de 5 "<<endl;
}
```

A malas también podrías usar una macro, aunque sería recomendable la expresión constante. Es más moderna y posee tipado fuerte.

```
#define MAX_ELEMENTOS 5
```